# Magento email layout translate

Tags: magento

Hi I translate magento system but I dont know where can I find text which come when i order some product like Subtotal(Excl.Tax),Subtotal (Incl.Tax),Shipping & Handling (Excl.Tax),Shipping & Handling(Incl.Tax),Grand Total (Excl.Tax). Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to edit Magneto email templates.

1. The brute way is to edit files in `/app/locale/[language]-[country]/template/email/` which I don't recommend because those files may be overwritten with Magento update or update of your language pack.
2. More civilized way is to create your own email template and assign it to a corresponding action.

   To create a new email template go to `Admin\System\Transactional Emails`, add new template and select a base template from a drop-down. So for example for order confirmation email you need to select an appropriate base template which then will be loaded into editor area. Make required changes and save the email template.

   Now you have to assign your template to corresponding action. For example for order confirmation email you have to go to `Admin\System\Configuration\Sales\Sales Emails`. There you will find two fields `New Order Confirmation Template` and `New Order Confirmation Template for Guest`.

   That's all. I'm not sure if email templates are cached in Magento, so refresh your cache just to be sure.

Comment: Yes I have own email template it works fine but I cant translate Subtotal(Excl.Tax) and other things. It must be in other file.

Comment: I think those are in `/app/locale/[language]-[country]/Mage_Sales.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Tim's assumption about Mage_Sales.csv is partially right.
Lets looks at the latest Magento release (1.7.0.2):
app/locale/[Locale_Code]/template/email/sales/order_new.html

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

this sends us to app/design/frontend/[Your_Package]/[Your_Theme]/layout/sales.xml

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_items>
```

So you can find all loaded templates

email/order/items.phtml defines view for the list of all ordered products

email/order/items/order/default.phtml standard prices(Inc., Excl. taxes), and gift messge

sales/order/totals.phtml, tax/order/tax.phtml totals, grand total, taxes and so on

you can check these templates for used helpers and csv files: Mage_Sales.csv, Mage_Tax.csv, Mage_Weee.csv.

Comment: your answer is really help ful

Answer (score -1):

Magento Email Templates are using the trans directive. It means.

```
{{trans "Text in english"}}
```

you have to translate as

```
{{trans "Text in your language"}}
```

Comment: Your answer is not proper, provide proper explanation as to how to put this to translate it exactly